# Manually build an occupancy grid on ros

Tags: ros

I am trying to build and publish a /nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid message to test another node that depends on actual data from a robot. Before I use real data, I just wanted to build a message from an array or matrix of numbers without any real sensors. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about record a rosbag using a virtual sensor in gazebo simulation

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` [message definition](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) you will see that the data is just stored as an array of `int8`s with some `MapMetaData`. So if you just need something filled in to test the other node without any assumptions about usefulness or plausibility of the data you can write a script that fills in random data into the data structure.

If the data needs to be somewhat useful and plausible you probably should have a look at the [Map Server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) package. It allows you to generate a `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` from an image. This approach might overall even be easier than generating random data.